# SDL Web 8 with .NET DXA 1.5: Internal links not updating consistently

Tags: web8, dxa, dynamic-linking, dxa-1.5, cache

I have a very strange issue with DXA 1.5 whereby an internal link will resolve correctly sometimes but not other times.

This only seems to occur on production where we have 3 load balanced web servers talking to 2 load balanced microservice API servers.

If I switch between the web servers by direct URL I can see differences in links on each server and sometimes different results for the same server after the cache has cleared.

It seems to me like 1 of the API servers is not resolving links correctly. We are using Active MQ to invalidate the object cache on the API servers and this seems to be working correctly.

Is there a different cache for links?

Comment: I would recommend to report this with SDL Customer Support.

Comment: Hi Rick - we have a case open with SDL support currently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SDL issued a hotfix for this issue. It was caused by the service-caching on the CIL having a sliding expiration which meant that regularly requested content was not falling out of the cache when published. Hotfix is: CD_8.1.1.2889

A second hotfix was issued for the deployer as it was not clearing Component links in a scaled out scenario - hot fix is: CD_8.1.1.3556, which may also have been a factor in this issue.